# Django scheduled Tasks - Alternative to Cron or Independent Daemon

Tags: python, django, cron, daemon

In creating scheduled tasks I've used both Cron and a specially set up daemon for django.

Cron is silly-simple, and the daemon (in my opinion) might be excessive. The daemon set up an independent Django instance.

Django itself (If I'm not mistaken) runs as a daemon anyway, correct?

I'm wondering - how do you schedule tasks within the Django environment without leaving off from standard use?

Comment: No, Django does not typically run as a daemon. Plus, it is inextricably tied to the request/response cycle, which is why you need something else for scheduled tasks.

Comment: if you google "django cron" you'll probably find some others, such as this: http://django-cron.readthedocs.org/ which is sort of a middle ground

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to run [periodic tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) but depending on what are you trying to do it could be overkill.

If your use case it's simple, cron+management command it's way easier. You can use [Kronos](https://github.com/jgorset/django-kronos), [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) or [any of this libraries](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cron/) for this